# How to generate pivot table data(Summary data) from Hyperledger fabric blocks

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Im developing an app using Hyperledger Fabric to store data to show strong trust between parties, i need to generate summary report at end of the day. Im not sure if its possible on Fabric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something such as build a pivot table, or do some analytics on the data in a blockchain, then you would likely want to maintain a separate data store/lake by subscribing to the events published when transactions are committed and updating the datastore accordingly. You could query the world state via chaincode, but frankly, it would not be the most efficient solution.